# Images from wp-page larger than the max width (Wordpress - Graphql - Gatsby)

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I have always had problems bringing in the images from wordpress via gatsby with graphql (

```
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: page.html,
        }}
      />
```

)

This new error is the image is coming in from wordpress at full size. Which is HUGE lol

Do I need to edit SCSS or is this a wordpress issue?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgY4Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to edit SCSS or is this a wordpress issue?

It is not an error *per se*, and it's not certainly a WordPress issue, since the image is being fetched and retrieved properly. It's a simple CSS (or SCSS) issue where the images are unstyled.

You can simply target them by adding a class name to the `div` and adding the corresponding CSS.